# Accessing bits from union without shifting in C++

Tags: c++

I am writing a data packer for my game.  The idea is to write something that can pack attributes, stream data over the network and other areas where data packing can be desirable.  I have used a version of http://cplusplus.com/articles/zb07M4Gy/ to achieve part of my goal.  My code looks like:

```cpp
namespace detail
{
    // Determine whether _Type is signed or unsigned.
    // _Result is then either a signed or unsigned char
    template < typename _Type >
    struct sign
    {
        typedef typename std::_If< std::tr1::is_unsigned< _Type >::value, unsigned char, signed char >::_Type _Result;
    };
}

// Template for packing and unpacking data
// at bit and byte level
template < typename _Type >
struct packer
{
    typedef typename _Type  value_type;

    static const int num_bytes = sizeof(value_type);
    static const int num_bits  = num_bytes * CHAR_BIT;

    union
    {
        value_type packed_value;
        typename detail::sign< value_type >::_Result byte[num_bytes];
    };
};
```

My question is, how can I extend this code to allow access to the individual bits without bit shifting?  I cannot use std::bitset since it has a non-trivial constructor and an array of bool would result in allocating a byte for each entry instead of a bit.

Ideally I would like to avoid bit setting/checking macros (although, it does seem my hands may be tied).  There are portability and endian issues, but those aside, is there a way to achieve my goal?

An idea I had was to use something like:

```
template< int _NumBits >
struct bit_field
{
    bit_field< _NumBits - 1 > the_other_bits;

    int value : 1;

    int operator[](const int in_index)
    {
        return reinterpret_cast< int* >(this)[index];
    }
};

template<  >
struct bit_field< 0 >
{
    int value : 1;

    int operator[](const int in_index)
    {
        return reinterpret_cast< int* >(this)[index];
    }
};
```

Which would recursively build an array.  However the problem with this (obviously) is alignment, which for this struct is 4bytes in MSVC10 giving the packer struct a total of 132 bytes, which is obviously not ideal when working with a 4 byte integer...

Any suggestions (including "man up and use bit shifting"...) are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bitfields:

```
struct byte
{
    bool bit0 : 1;
    bool bit1 : 1;
    bool bit2 : 1;
    bool bit3 : 1;
    bool bit4 : 1;
    bool bit5 : 1;
    bool bit6 : 1;
    bool bit7 : 1;
};
```

and then in your union

```
union something
{
    byte bytes[num_of_bytes];

};
```

Comment: I am very tempted to go down this road. I'm fairly certain that I'm not going to be working on a system where CHAR_BIT is some number other than 8 so assuming 8bit bytes is safe. Also, plus one for providing an answer that doesn't use bit shifting

Answer (score 1):

Save your future from hours of brain-ache by using bitshifting.

More specifically, when doing this level of bit-packing, you don't want to abstract it away in a higher level and trust the compiler to do what you expect.    You should explicitly spell out and document the bitsize, order and layout of the data going over the network, and the order they are stored on your particular platform.   And then you will need a platform-specific section to deal with the fact that the storage is different from one processor type to the next.    You can still write client code which is oblivious to the bit-level structure, but your data packing code should be as explicit as possible.

Comment: Isn't the whole language designed around bitshifting? *g*

Answer (score 1):

With custom packing and unpacking you need to know in advance what kind of data is in your packed data in order to unpack it.This means you will have a lot of coupling between the part using the data, and the part packing and unpacking the data.

Oh, I added an atrribute, let's modify my packer / unpacker to take this into account. It sucks and it won't save you that much space.

So if you are really worried about the amount of data you will have to send, use compression, like lzo, or gzip or even nothing.

This way you don't need to have two representation of each of your datatype. You can debug your sending / receiving code without compression, then add compression / decompression without telling the rest of your program.

Regarding the question, if you still intend to do packing :
use bitshifting first. If at some point you find it awful and error-prone etc...,
at least you will have a working example base to find a more general method.

Writing a generalist method first usually means overengineering or getting it wrong. Starting with a more simple and ad-hoc method means that when you come to the point were you eventually need something new, you have some experience with the problem.

Comment: I have written plenty of bit shifting code in my relatively short time as a programmer. My hope was just to make my above structure more feature complete. You are right that my approach is overkill for a first attempt at packing, but as I mentioned it isn't my first attempt here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could define a bunch of constants that relate to the bit position of the attribute you want to check:

```
const UINT8 BITPOS_ATT_ISMALE =  1;
const UINT8 BITPOS_ATT_ISCUST =  2;
const UINT8 BITPOS_ATT_NOCALL =  4; 
const UINT8 BITPOS_ATT_NOSMS  =  8; //and so on for 16, 32, 64, however many you need
```

and then you will not need to shift just use a bitwise AND to determine if the attribute is set.

EG:

```
bool isAttSet(UINT8 attributeToCheck, UINT8 attributeSet)
{
    return ( attributeToCheck &  attributeSet);
}
```

Input 01001101 returns true for BITPOS_ATT_ISMALE, BITPOS_ATT_NOCALL, and BITPOS_ATT_NOSMS but not BITPOS_ATT_ISCUST.

EDIT: Just to be clear, you would be passing in the "packed_value" and you would need to match the attribute size depending on your template class.

Comment: BITPOS_ATT_NOCALL should be 0x04 unless it's supposed to imply both ismale and iscust.

Comment: 4 decimal = 0x4 hex? Did you catch me before the first edit? It was accidentally 0x03 for a minute.